# Power shell script to get Computer Description + OU details

Tags: active-directory, powershell

Power shell script to get Computer Description + OU details

I do not get any output when I try

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> Get-ADComputer -Computername "ABCD1DT001"
```

I need to be able to get "Computer Object Description" and "distinguished name (OU)" of 100 remote machines.

Comment: I posted an answer below, but you should have done some research on the commandlet first to try and figure out why you were receiving the error, and if you did do that you should have stated what steps you took in trying to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `-computername` is not a valid parameter for the `Get-ADComputer` commandlet.

You want to use the `-identity` parameter instead.

```
Get-ADComputer -identity "ABCD1DT001"
```

Now in order to retrieve the `Description` value, you will have to specify that property in your command, since it is not one of the properties which are retrieved by default.  The `Name` and `DistinguishedName` properties are retrieved by default for this commandlet.

```
Get-ADComputer -Identity "ABCD1DT001" -Properties Description | ft -a Name,DistinguishedName,Description
```

Lastly, to run this for your 100 machines, you can create a loop against the list of machines and then display the results in the format you choose.

```
$results = get-content c:\textfilewithcomputernames.txt | % { Get-ADComputer -Identity $_ -Properties Description }
$results | ft -a Name,DistinguishedName,Description
```